# change color of back arrow in navigation header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've modified the standard behavior of back button in navigation bar

using this code :

```
export class QuranSouratesPage extends React.Component{
  static navigationOptions =({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Le noble Coran',
    headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('SearchPage')}}/>,
});
```

now i have the right behavior except for the color of the arrow which became black now, i'cant find a way to change the color of the the arrow i've tried to style  using tintColor but no result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `tintColor` prop to `HeaderBackButton`

```
export class QuranSouratesPage extends React.Component{
  static navigationOptions =({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Le noble Coran',
    headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton tintColor={'white'} onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('SearchPage')}}/>,
});
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/react-navigation-dynamic-routes)

Comment: Along with this, if you set `headerTintColor` in the stack, then to get that color you can do this: `headerLeft: props => <HeaderBackButton {...props} /* your custom props */ />`

Comment: thanks for the help! `tintColor={'white'} `  inside HeaderBackButton element made the job.

Answer (score 8):

You can add **headerTintColor** in your Stack.Navigator

```
<Stack.Screen name="YourPage" component={YourComponent}
    options={{ headerTintColor: '#ffffff'}}
/>
```